# What does <error-manager><only-once> mean in jboss-logging.xml

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss6.x

does anyone know what

```
<error-manager>
    <only-once/>
</error-manager>
```

mean in jboss-logging.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it sets the [log4j error handler](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/ErrorHandler.html) to be an instance of the `OnlyOnceErrorHandler` class.

Quoting the relevant [JavaDoc page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/OnlyOnceErrorHandler.html):

> The `OnlyOnceErrorHandler` implements
>   log4j's default error handling policy
>   which consists of emitting a message
>   for the first error in an appender and
>   ignoring all following errors.
>
> The error message is printed on
>   `System.err`.
>
> This policy aims at protecting an
>   otherwise working application from
>   being flooded with error messages when
>   logging fails.

Comment: Here you can find the source of the JBoss `OnlyOnceErrorHandler` class: http://source.jboss.org/browse/JBossCommon/jboss-logmanager/trunk/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/errormanager/OnlyOnceErrorManager.java?r=3331.